# Svelte/Sapper: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module in sapper build

Tags: svelte, sapper

While using sapper , I don't get error while running sapper in dev mode. But I get "Failed to fetch dynamically imported module " while running sapper build using npm run start. Sometimes it works and sometimes I get error